# Sidr Navigation is not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, sidr

I try to make [this](http://www.germania-leipzig.de/)  site responsible. For this task I was trying to get the [sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#getstarted) plugin to work. But nothing happen :(. Can someone help me to find the issue?

**my functions.php:**

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');  
}

function lbg_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'lbg_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lbg_css.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'sidr_style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.sidr.dark.css' );

    wp_register_script( 'sidr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.sidr.min.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', false );
    wp_register_script( 'js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/js.js' , array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', false );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'sidr' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'lbg_enqueue_scripts' );

function viewport_meta() {
    ?>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <?php
}
add_filter('wp_head', 'viewport_meta');
```

**my header.php:**

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
      <div id="mainpic"></div>
      <div id="mobile-header">
        <a id="responsive-menu-button" >Menu</a>
      </div>
      <div id="mynavigation">
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul id="pagetabs">
                <?php wp_list_pages('exclude=13&sort_column=post_date&title_li='); ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**my js.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

      $('#responsive-menu-button').sidr({
        name: 'sidr-main',
        source: '#mynavigation'
        });
    })
```

**my lbg_css.css:**

```
#mobile-header {
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){
    #mobile-header {
        display: block;
    }

    #page {
            text-align: right;
    }
}
```

I really don't know what to do yet? For my understanding this is the way to get it to work...but nope, the menu does not change when the window resizes, just the text-align (for test).

Please help!

Many thanks, Jan from germany!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are going to have a few issues integrating this to wordpress. Wordpress runs in no conflict mode so to start:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('#responsive-menu-button').sidr({
    name: 'sidr-main',
    source: '#mynavigation'
    });
})
```

next check the console (google chrome right click and inspect element, see console? thats were js errors appear). Work through the issues as you find them.

Comment: Thanks for the no-conflict tip, I changed my code. But still no responsive menu and unfortunately no errors in my console (firebug). Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much David :). Everything is fine now, the no-conflict solution was the one who saved my problem. I couldnt see the menu-link cause it was under the header. With position: absolute I found the link and everything was good :)